# Admob not approved review request

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

Anyone would like to tell me how to solve this " Layout encourages accidental clicks - unexpected launch interstitial".
But I already updated my app on play store and remove all the interstitial ads. Then I requested review 
But admob not approved . Please tell me how to solve this error/warning

[Admob Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mufmr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you need to perform the action on ad dismissed callback. If you load/show ad with action, you will be blocked by admob.

You can find correct implementation here.

http://hackerseve.com/android-using-together-admob-and-facebook-audience-network/

PS- you can try Facebook Audience Network as well as suggested in example